# How to hide changes tracking for good in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Everytime I open my `docx` it shows the changes panel. When I hide it (Revision tab -> Final revision) it solves my problem, but just until I close the app. When I open it again I have to repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable change tracking, accept all changes and de-select change tracking. If you just want to hide the changes panel, there's a setting for how it displays your changes, and you can disable that panel (I apologize for the lack of specifics - I no longer have access to a Word 2007 installation).

**EDIT**

Here's instructions for [Word 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305216) and [Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/turn-on-or-off-change-tracking-HA001218995.aspx). Hope this helps!